# Sort Tuple of chemical and coeff

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

I have a list of tuples that i want to sort in numerical order by the second value in the tuple. A sample of the list im working with is:

```
[('H2O', '6'), ('O2', '4')]
```

so what i would want in this case is:

```
[('O2','4'),('H2O',6')]
```

I know this is really basic I just can seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with chemicals and coefficients, if you try to express the problem in a more general way then you are more likely to find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `key` parameter of `sort`:

```
mylist.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

This will convert the second element in the tuple to an integer, and sort by these integers.

Since your tuples contain numbers in the second element, it makes more sense to store numbers in the tuples rather than strings. If you do so, you can sort with:

```
import operator
mylist.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> l = [('H2O', '6'), ('O2', '4')]
>>> l.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[1]))
>>> l
[('O2', '4'), ('H2O', '6')]
```

`sort` method does `in-place` sorting, and hence modifies your `list`.

You can also use `sorted` function, which returns the sorted list while leaving the original list unmodified.

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
[('O2', '4'), ('H2O', '6')]
>>> l
[('H2O', '6'), ('O2', '4')]  # Original list unmodified
```

Often we use `sorted` function, if we want to iterate over a sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `key` argument of `sort` (or [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)). It is a function that is passed every element of the iterable (in this case, each tuple).

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)...

```
In [1]: import operator

In [2]: chem = [('H2O', '6'), ('O2', '4')]

In [3]: sorted(chem, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
Out[3]: [('O2', '4'), ('H2O', '6')]
```

or a simple function:

```
In [4]: sorted(chem, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[4]: [('O2', '4'), ('H2O', '6')]
```

Edit: [interjay is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13938893/1258041): it's better to convert the second item to a number:

```
sorted(chem, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Otherwise they will be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first `import operator` 
Now use the `key` parameter to `list.sort()`:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

For faster,

```
list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```