# How do operator.itemgetter() and sort() work?

Tags: python, sorting, operator-keyword

I have the following code:

```
# initialize
a = []

# create the table (name, age, job)
a.append(["Nick", 30, "Doctor"])
a.append(["John",  8, "Student"])
a.append(["Paul", 22, "Car Dealer"])
a.append(["Mark", 66, "Retired"])    

# sort the table by age
import operator
a.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))    

# print the table
print(a)
```

It creates a 4x3 table and then it sorts it by age. My question is, what exactly `key=operator.itemgetter(1)` does? Does the `operator.itemgetter` function return the item's value? Why can't I just type something like `key=a[x][1]` there? Or can I? How could with operator print a certain value of the form like `3x2` which is `22`?

1. How does exactly Python sort the table? Can I reverse-sort it?
2. How can I sort it based on two columns like first age, and then if age is the same b name?
3. How could I do it without `operator`?

Comment: Related to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Looks like you're a little bit confused about all that stuff.

`operator` is a built-in module providing a set of convenient operators. In two words `operator.itemgetter(n)` constructs a callable that assumes an iterable object (e.g. list, tuple, set) as input, and fetches the n-th element out of it.

So, you can't use `key=a[x][1]` there, because python has no idea what `x` is. Instead, you could use a `lambda` function (`elem` is just a variable name, no magic there):

```
a.sort(key=lambda elem: elem[1])
```

Or just an ordinary function:

```
def get_second_elem(iterable):
    return iterable[1]

a.sort(key=get_second_elem)
```

So, here's an important note: in python functions are [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), so you can pass them to other functions as a parameter.

Other questions:

1. Yes, you can reverse sort, just add `reverse=True`:  `a.sort(key=..., reverse=True)`
2. To sort by more than one column you can use `itemgetter` with multiple indices: `operator.itemgetter(1,2)`, or with lambda: `lambda elem: (elem[1], elem[2])`. This way, iterables are constructed on the fly for each item in list, which are than compared against each other in lexicographic(?) order (first elements compared, if equal - second elements compared, etc)
3. You can fetch value at [3,2] using `a[2,1]` (indices are zero-based). Using operator... It's possible, but not as clean as just indexing.

Refer to the documentation for details:

1. [`operator.itemgetter` explained](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)
2. [Sorting list by custom key in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions)

Comment: How would you sort reversed by one column and not reversed by another column?

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(n)` doesn't seem to work with `set` or `dict` (maybe it will work with `dict` if `n` is a valid key instead of some `int` you come up with).

Comment: @Vim [According to docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), for dict it should work with any hashable value. `itemgetter(n)` means it'll try to do dict.__getitem__ lookup, which (unless you're not actually using a dict, but a custom class extending dict and overriding __getitem__) is equivalent to `dict[n]` - and it will obviously  fail if there are no `n` key in the dict. For dicts where you're not sure if a key exists you might want to stick with something like `lambda key: dict.get(key, None)` or similar.

Example: https://ideone.com/PJk8vd

Comment: @yayitswei if one column is a number, use `lambda row: (row.one_thing, -row.number_thing)`, supplying `reverse=True` if you want to reverse by `one_thing`. If you don't have an easy numeric option like that, you'd have to finagle more.

Comment: Is it possible to sort by two columns by only one of them reversed?

Comment: @yahyitswei yes, please see the itemgetter sorting solution for varying reverse arguments for multiple columns here, you then need to arrange your sorting in multiple steps in a row: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466068/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-second-value-reverse-true-and-then-by-key-reverse-fal

Answer (score 55):

### Answer for Python beginners

In simpler words:

1. The `key=` parameter of `sort` requires a key *function* (to be applied to be objects to be sorted) rather than a single key *value* and
2. that is just what `operator.itemgetter(1)` will give you: A *function* that grabs the first item from a list-like object.

(More precisely those are *callables*, not functions, but that is a difference that can often be ignored.)

Comment: Thank you - as a still-learning python programmer, THIS is what I was looking for to understand what was happening.  It wasn't clear to me that ".sort(key = attrgetter("index"))" in my code was sending the FUNCTION attrgetter() with the argument "index" to the Sort() function; I thought it was sending a result as in C and other languages.

Comment: @Locane: No, that is not what's happening. `attrgetter` will construct an appropriate function for you and return it. It _is_ sending a "result". Only that result is a function.

Answer (score 22):

You are asking a lot of questions that you could answer yourself by [reading the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), so I'll give you a general advice: read it and experiment in the python shell. You'll see that `itemgetter` returns a callable:

```
>>> func = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> func(a)
['Paul', 22, 'Car Dealer']
>>> func(a[0])
8
```

To do it in a different way, you can use `lambda`:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

And reverse it:

```
a.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Sort by more than one column:

```
a.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))
```

See the [sorting How To](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
#sorting first by age then profession,you can change it in function "fun".
a = []

def fun(v):
    return (v[1],v[2])

# create the table (name, age, job)
a.append(["Nick", 30, "Doctor"])
a.append(["John",  8, "Student"])
a.append(["Paul",  8,"Car Dealer"])
a.append(["Mark", 66, "Retired"])

a.sort(key=fun)


print a
```

Comment: this solution is without using operator

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
a.append(["Nick", 30, "Doctor"])
a.append(["John",  8, "Student"])
a.append(["Paul",  8,"Car Dealer"])
a.append(["Mark", 66, "Retired"])
print a

[['Nick', 30, 'Doctor'], ['John', 8, 'Student'], ['Paul', 8, 'Car Dealer'], ['Mark', 66, 'Retired']]

def _cmp(a,b):     

    if a[1]<b[1]:
        return -1
    elif a[1]>b[1]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

sorted(a,cmp=_cmp)

[['John', 8, 'Student'], ['Paul', 8, 'Car Dealer'], ['Nick', 30, 'Doctor'], ['Mark', 66, 'Retired']]

def _key(list_ele):

    return list_ele[1]

sorted(a,key=_key)

[['John', 8, 'Student'], ['Paul', 8, 'Car Dealer'], ['Nick', 30, 'Doctor'], ['Mark', 66, 'Retired']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to sort an array using a user-defined function is to use cmp_to_key from Functools.
here is a sample code:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def mine(x,y):
    if(x[1]!=y[1]): return x[1]>y[1]
    else: return x[0]>y[0]
    
a = []
a.append(["Nick", 30, "Doctor"])
a.append(["John",  8, "Student"])
a.append(["Paul", 22, "Car Dealer"])
a.append(["Mark", 66, "Retired"])  

def mine(a,b):
    if a[1] > b[1]:
        return 1
    elif a[1] < b[1]:
        return -1
    else:
        if a[0] > b[0]:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
                     
print(sorted(a,key = cmp_to_key(mine)))
```