# How to sort student data by grade (ascending) then by name (descending)?

Tags: python, sorting

```
10
John Seen 3.7
Bill Stark 2.06
Jack Connor 3.47
Drake Mason 3.05
Bill Callum 2.83
Emma Jake 3.65
William Damian 3.33
James Charlie 3.56
Oscar Rhys 3.78
George Reece 2.52
```

So if there are same "GPA" numbers (value) it should sort it by key (descending).

Following code sorts by value then sorts by key, but ascending

```
n = int(input())
grades = {}
result = ''
for i in range(n):
    student = input().split()
    grades[student[0] + ' ' + student[1]] = eval(student[2])

sorted_d = sorted(grades.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
for i in sorted_d:
    print(str(i[0]) + " - " + str(i[1]))
```

Comment: Please make your data a reproducible example: `dat = list[ ('John Seen',3.7), ('Bill Stark',2.06)...]`

Answer (score 0):

There are several misunderstandings in your code:

- You chose a dict `grades` with key (student name) and value (GPA/grade)
- Bad choice. You can't directly "sort" the tuples of (key, value) of a dictionary. So `dict` is the wrong choice.
- Instead you wanted the data to be a **list** of lists/tuples of `(student,grade)`
- So you shouldn't have used a dict for `grades`, you should use a list. (However since it's now a list of `(student,grade)` tuples, so call it e.g. `sg` or `student_grades` or `dat` or something).
- Then your sort function will be pretty simple. If only you didn't need ascending order on col 1, but descending order on col 0, you could do  `l.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))`. But you need different orders, so that forces you to use a custom `sort(cmp=...)` See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595686/how-does-operator-itemgetter-and-sort-work-in-python)

I leave it to you to refactor your code. Looks like a fairly simple exercise once you decompose it right. **The moral of the story is think carefully about your choice of data structure(s) for the task you need to do: the right choice will make things simple; the wrong choice will create problems**, then you need to revisit your initial assumptions and consider the alternatives.

Comment: @slider: I don't know for sure that it's a homework exercise, but it sure looks like one. I think giving hints and explaining principles is the best way to respond. (And if the OP does subsequently post code with a specific issue, can help them with that. But not give the full code solution upfront.)