# Python sorted function on django-queryset objects

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I am first trying to sort by created_on descending and then using the same product_users queryset and applying sorted function on foreign_key user object where field is name.

```
product_users = ProductUser.objects.filter(entity=entity).order_by('-created_on')
product_users = sorted(product_users, key=lambda pu(pu.user.name.lower(), pu.status))
```

I want to apply order by descending on second column pu.status

Comment: User model in django doesn't have "name" field. Use "user.first_name" or "user.last_name" instead.

Comment: @SeyyedSajjadSanikhani have overridden the User model and created a User model field which takes name as combination of first_name and last_name

Comment: So try this for key value in sorted:
key=lambda x: x.user.name

Comment: @SeyyedSajjadSanikhani how can i order by multiple columns with same sorted function as you can see i now want to order by descending on status column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using two sorted function on same go for both first sort by status descending and then sort by user name ascending.

```
product_users = sorted(product_users, key=lambda pu: (sorted(pu.status, reverse=True), pu.user.name.lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by multiple attributes, you should make lambda function to return a tuple of attributes instead one. so you can try:

```
sorted(product_users, key=lambda pu: (pu.user.name.lower(), pu.status)
```

But if you want to sort ascending by former attribute and sort descending by latter attribute, you can use a function as explained in

[Python Sort Function Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```py
def multisort(xs, specs):
    for key, reverse in reversed(specs):
        xs.sort(key=attrgetter(key), reverse=reverse)
    return xs
```

So **xs** is our list that we want to sort and **specs** is a list including tuples as each tuple for an attribute: `('attr_name', reverse)`

Comment: how to implement the same def multisort(xs, specs): to my scenario, the function seems quite confusing.

Comment: I have come up with this approach which works: product_users = sorted(product_users, key=lambda pu: (pu.user.name.lower(), sorted(pu.status, reverse=True)))

Comment: Okay pls let me know what is the right approach to achieve what i need. thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's very complicated to use inline sorted, Or maybe impossible.
Only way that i think is working definitely is to use 2 sorted functions. First by status in descending order and second by .user.name.lower() in ascending order.

Comment: yes i am using two sorted functions which first sort gives sort by name and second sort by status in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.8+ , you can **annotate** user's name in lowercase to the queryset and then use order_by to sort

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
       
product_users  = product_users.annotate(name_lower=Lower('user__name'))
product_users  = product_users.order_by('name_lower', '-status')
```

**Edit:**
If you really need to use sorted function for some reason, please try the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466068/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-second-value-reverse-true-and-then-by-key-reverse-fal)

Comment: I have come up with this approach which works: product_users = sorted(product_users, key=lambda pu: (pu.user.name.lower(), sorted(pu.status, reverse=True)))

Comment: The right way to do this in Django is to first annotate and then use order_by. Using sorted for such sorting is complicated.