# Sorting a list in Descending numerical order and if number is the same, sort by Ascending alphabetical in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have 2 lists where I have to sort them both by descending order in the second list.

```
lst1 = ['Chris','Amanda','Boris','Charlie']
lst2 = [35,43,55,35]
```

I have sorted them by using

```
lst2, lst1 = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(lst2, lst1), reverse=True)))
```

Because they are sorted using `reverse=True` my result is sorted by descending alphabetical order as well

This produces the result
`['Boris', 'Amanda', 'Chris', 'Charlie'], [55, 43, 35, 35]`

is there a way to produce the result
`['Boris', 'Amanda', 'Charlie', 'Chris'], [55, 43, 35, 35]`?

Comment: What do these two lists have to do with each other? Why not sort them individually? `"I have 2 lists where I have to sort them both by descending order in the second list."` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466068/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-second-value-reverse-true-and-then-by-key-reverse-fal) and the answers there work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst1 = ['Chris','Amanda','Boris','Charlie']
lst2 = [35,43,55,35]

lst1, lst2 = zip(*sorted(zip(lst1, lst2), key=lambda p: (-p[1], p[0])))
```

This produces:

```
>>> lst1
['Boris', 'Amanda', 'Charlie', 'Chris']
>>> lst2
[55, 43, 35, 35]
>>>
```

Comment: I just updated this.  The comprehension wan't necessary so I removed it.