# Ordering a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list, my_list:

```
[['28/02/2014, apples']
['09/07/2014, oranges']
['22/04/2014, bananas']
['14/03/2014, tomatoes']]
```

which I am trying to order by date. This is the code I am using:

```
def display(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        x = ([item[0] + ": " + item[1]])
        print x
```

I've tried applying different forms of sorting to x (sorted, x.sort(), etc) but nothing seems to work. How can I get the list to sort by date, from earliest to latest?

Comment: I'm very confused by what your code actually looks like. That first block of code is not "a list of tuples", it is four separate single-element lists each containing exactly one string.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the list is actually what the function displays at the moment, without sorting. I'll try and edit it to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: @Gilles I doubt it is a duplicate - there are dates inside of strings - it makes the question different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sorted()` with applying a `key` function that takes the first item from every sublist, splits it by `:` and converts the part before the colon to `datetime` using `strptime()`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> l = [['28/02/2014: apples'], ['09/07/2014: oranges'], ['22/04/2014: bananas'], ['14/03/2014: tomatoes']]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0].split(':')[0], '%d/%m/%Y'))
[['28/02/2014: apples'],  
 ['14/03/2014: tomatoes'], 
 ['22/04/2014: bananas'], 
 ['09/07/2014: oranges']]
```