# Arrange a list of tuples by integer

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples, with each tuple containing information about an employee.

```
EmpList= [('1253', 'Fred'), ('889', 'Sue'), ('1389', 'Sally')]
```

I'd like to arrange them in increasing order by their employee number. Using sorted, my first inclination, doesn't work since the numbers aren't integers. Hence

```
sorted(EmpList)
[('1253', 'Fred'), ('1389', 'Sally'), ('889', 'Sue')]
```

when I'd like

```
[('889', 'Sue'), ('1253', 'Fred'), ('1389', 'Sally')]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lambda` for that:

```
a = [('1253', 'Fred'), ('1389', 'Sally'), ('889', 'Sue')]
b = sorted(a, key=lambda a: int(a[0]))
```

#### Your case

```
>>> EmpList = [('1253', 'Fred'), ('889', 'Sue'), ('1389', 'Sally')]
>>> b = sorted(a, key=lambda EmpList: int(EmpList[0]))
>>> b
[('889', 'Sue'), ('1253', 'Fred'), ('1389', 'Sally')]
```

To get reversed values, you can do:

```
>>> EmpList = [('1253', 'Fred'), ('889', 'Sue'), ('1389', 'Sally')]
>>> b = sorted(a, key=lambda EmpList: int(EmpList[0]), reversed=True)
>>> b
[('1389', 'Sally'), ('1253', 'Fred'), ('889', 'Sue')]
```

### Note

Note the importance of casting the `a[0]` as an int. This is because if you do not cast it as an int, python will do the comparisons on string and:

```
>>> '889' > '1253'
True
```

This is because when python compares the first character of each string, '8' is greater than '1' and therfore, `'889' > '1253'` evaluates to True.

This is definitely **not** what you want. So to do it properly, cast it as `int`.

Comment: The ``int`` cast is probably redundant, the string-sort for numbers will be equivalent and the cast is just as expensive as the string comparison.

Comment: @aruisdante, I tried it without the casting and it didn't work. Probably because '889' > '1253' in strings

Comment: though you could just use the ``reverse`` parameter to get the expected output.

Comment: @aruisdante: that won't suffice.  Consider `['2','10','3']`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the reason `'889 > 1253'` is the first element of `'889'` : `'8'` is greater than first element of `'1253'` : `'1'`.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird, python's string comp doesn't do what I thought it did. Seems it only holds true of numbers of equivalent digits.

Comment: @Akavall, Thank you! I have include that in my explanation.

Comment: Thank you! How might I arrange them in the opposite direction, in descending order? I tired sticking a reverse at the end, to no avail