# Sorting tuples in python based on their values

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am trying to print the top 10 frequent words using the following code. However, its not working. Any idea on how to fix it?

```
def reducer_count_words(self, word, counts):
    # send all (num_occurrences, word) pairs to the same reducer.
    # num_occurrences is so we can easily use Python's max() function.
    yield None, (sum(counts), word)




# discard the key; it is just None
def reducer_find_max_10_words(self, _, word_count_pairs):
    # each item of word_count_pairs is (count, word),
    # so yielding one results in key=counts, value=word

        tmp = sorted(word_count_pairs)[0:10]
        yield tmp
```

Comment: @Veedrac: more similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples

Comment: @Leftium I strongly disagree with your interpretation of the question. Also, how the hell did "its not working. Any idea on how to fix it?" get upvotes?

Comment: @Veedrac: my interpretation is based on the question title and the asker's responses to other answers.

Comment: @Leftium I stick by my opinion, but I don't really care about a question of this quality anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tmp = sorted(word_count_pairs, key=lambda pair: pair[0], reverse=True)[0:10]
```

**Explanation:**

- The `key` parameter of `sorted()` allows you to run a function on each element before comparison.
- `lambda pair: pair[0]` is a function that extracts the number from your word_count_pairs.
- `reverse` sorts in descending order, instead of ascending order.

Sources:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

---

*aside*: If you have many different words, sorting the entire list to find the top ten is inefficient. There are much more efficient algorithms. The `most_common()` method mentioned in another answers probably utilizes a more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) and its `most_common` method:

```
>>>from collections import Counter
>>>my_words = 'a a foo bar foo'
>>>Counter(my_words.split()).most_common()
[('foo', 2), ('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
```

Comment: I am using this command in my code but seeing this error:
unhashable type 'list'. If I want to use this format it seems like I cannot use `most.common()`

Comment: Hmm. That exact code works on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use [collections.most_common()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

Example:

```
most_common([n])
Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If n is not specified, most_common() returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily:

>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)
[('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: I am using this command in my code but seeing this error:
unhashable type 'list'. If I want to use this format it seems like I cannot use `most.common()`

Comment: Run `most_common()` on the list of words, not on the `(word, count)` tuples