# sort the crop contours python and opencv

Tags: python

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


idx =0 
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) >3000:
        idx += 1
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + ".jpg", roi)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
```

It works, but the crop contours saved randomly.
I need the crop image saved respected to X value from low to high.

Answer (score 0):

Contours are generated in (approximately) increasing Y order - so the X coordinate of the bounding box would be pseudo-random (depending only on the image)

You would have to accumulate the BoundingRects, sort them by x and then make the regions.

see [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: did you mean make the following

Comment: did you mean make the following

Comment: import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('Selection_063.png',0)
(thresh, im_bw)=cv2.threshold(im , 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
idx =0 
for cnt in contours:
 if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>200:
  idx += 1
  x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
  cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
  roi=im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
  (thresh, im_bw)=cv2.threshold(roi , 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  
  
  cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + ".jpg", im_bw)