# how to sort tuple value from list in python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have list of tuple values. I need to sort value by id from the tuple list. Can anyone help me to do this.

```
  l = [('abc','23'),('ghi','11'),('sugan','12'),('shankar','10')]
```

I need a output like this.

```
  l = [('shankar','10'),('ghi','11'),('sugan','12'),('abc','23')]
```

and also if i need to sort like this means

```
  l =  [('abc', '23'),('sugan', '12'),('ghi', '11'),('shankar', '10')]
```

Comment: There is a similar answer here (like Avinash Raj gave it): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may pass `key` param to sorted function.

```
>>> l = [('abc','23'),('ghi','11'),('sugan','12'),('shankar','10')]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
[('shankar', '10'), ('ghi', '11'), ('sugan', '12'), ('abc', '23')]
>>>
```

Comment: if i need to sort like this means [('abc', '23'),('sugan', '12'),('ghi', '11'),('shankar', '10')]

Comment: if you want it in descending order just use `sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to sort

```
sorted(yourList, key=lambda tupVal: float(tupVal[1]))
```