# How to sort list of tuples using both elements of tuple?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I want to sort by first element in tuple, and, if first element for some tuples is equal, by second element.
For example, I have `[(5,1),(1,2),(1,1),(4,3)]` and I want to get `[(1,1),(1,2),(4,3),(5,1)]`

How can I do it in pythonic way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Answer (score 2):

```
d = [(5,1),(1,2),(1,1),(4,3)]
print(sorted(d,key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1])))
```

if you want better performance use `itemgetter`

Comment: The key is not required.

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator
l = [(5,1),(1,2),(1,1),(4,3)]
print(sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to specify the `key` since you want to sort on the list item itself.

```
>>> d = [(5,1),(1,2),(1,1),(4,3)]
>>> sorted(d)
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (4, 3), (5, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, **Sorted** method will return a list object. In this case **d** still remains unsorted.

If you want to sort d you can use

```
>>>d.sort()
```

Hope it helps