# Sorting a list of tuples by the addition of second and third element of the tuple

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have a list of tuples which is :

```
[('g', 10, 2), ('o', 6, 11), ('v', 2, 4), ('t', 1, 15), ('x', 40, 3), ('m', 4, 4), ('k', 10, 2), ('f', 14, 1), ('p', 70, 90), ('l', 21, 7), ('n', 1, 27), ('a', 39, 70), ('d', 11, 10), ('h', 21, 10), ('c', 10, 19), ('b', 8, 1), ('e', 30, 39), ('i', 23, 29), ('r', 8, 7), ('q', 2, 2), ('s', 18, 86)]
```

and I'm struggling about how to sort them so they can be placed like this:

```
[('p', 70, 90), ('a', 39, 70), ('s', 18, 84), ('è', 27, 45), ('e', 30, 39), ('i', 23, 29), ('x', 40, 3), ('h', 21, 10), ('c', 10, 19), ('l', 20, 7), ('d', 11, 10), ('o', 6, 11), ('t', 1, 15), ('f', 14, 1), ('r', 8, 7), ('g', 10, 2), ('k', 10, 2), ('n', 1, 11), ('b', 8, 1), ('m', 4, 4), ('v', 2, 4), ('q', 2, 2)]
```

It should be the addition of the second and third element of the tuple , and when they are the same ex. `(a,10,9)` and `(b,9,10)` they should be sorted alphabetically. It's written in python 3.5 and I can't call any library

Comment: You subjet line says sort by 2nd or 3rd, but your words say "the addition of the 2nd and 3rd element... when they are the same sort alphabetically"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: @Doctorlove Sorry I'm going to edit it , i was about to ask the wrong question

Answer (score 6):

You can set a tuple as the key to sort your list:

```
sorted(lst, key = lambda x: (sum(x[1:]), x[0]))
```

In this way, it will firstly sort by the sum of the last two elements of the tuple and then by the first element of the tuple.

And if you like the result in descending order, as @Moses commented, you can specify the the `reverse` parameter to be `True`:

```
sorted(lst, key = lambda x: (sum(x[1:]), x[0]), reverse = True)
```

*Update*:
To handle descending, ascending order differently, since the `sum` here is numeric, you can negate the `sum` as well. In this way, it will be sorted in descending order for the `sum` but alphabetically for the first letter.

```
sorted(lst, key = lambda x: (-sum(x[1:]), x[0]))
```

Comment: A `reverse=True` would be required considering OP's output

Comment: Does it need a `reverse = True` or did i misunderstand the question?

Comment: @doctorlove Yep. OP's result seems to prefer descending order.

Comment: @Psidom That answer sorts alphabetically only if the first element of the tuple is a 1 character word? Or it works for words of x lenght aswell?

Comment: @over96 It shouldn't matter how long the word is. It will compare starting from the first letter of the word just like how list is compared in python.

Comment: @Psidom oh wait i got where the problem is , when i use 
<code> reverse = True <code>
 it does the reverse with the alphabethical order aswell

Comment: That's correct. I don't think you can specify the sum in descending order and word in ascending order at the same time with `sorted()` function only.

Comment: @Psidom Well I "can't use modules which are not in the standard library"

Comment: You can negate the `sum` to solve this specific problem here since it's numeric.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: (sum(x[1:3]), x[0]))
```

Where `a` is your list. If you need reversed:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: (sum(x[1:3]), x[0]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Could you explain me the 1:3?

Comment: @over96 it is a slice. that is how you get 2nd and 3rd element of list. You can replace it with lambda x: x[1] + x[2]

Comment: Oh okay , thank you. A last question , how can I reverse this kind of sorting?

Comment: @Alex This answer won't sort alphabetically if they are equal

Comment: @brianpck fixed

Comment: @Alex Not yet: you need parentheses

Comment: You don't need `[1:one beyond end]`, `[1:]` just works

Comment: @doctorlove works if size of tuple is  3, it's not clear if it is always like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('g', 10, 2), ('o', 6, 11), ('v', 2, 4), ('t', 1, 15),
     ('x', 40, 3), ('m', 4, 4), ('k', 10, 2), ('f', 14, 1),
     ('p', 70, 90), ('l', 21, 7), ('n', 1, 27), ('a', 39, 70),
     ('d', 11, 10), ('h', 21, 10), ('c', 10, 19), ('b', 8, 1),
     ('e', 30, 39), ('i', 23, 29), ('r', 8, 7), ('q', 2, 2),
     ('s', 18, 86)]
```

[Create a function that will return the sum of the items](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and use that function a the sort key.  I like to use operator.itemgetter() when extracting items from iterables.

```
import operator
second_third_first_items = operator.itemgetter(1, 2, 0)
def key(thing):
    *two_three, one = second_third_first_items(thing)
    return (sum(two_three), one)
a.sort(key = key, reverse = True)
```

---

`key` without operator.itemgetter

```
def key(thing):
    one, *two_three = thing[:3]
    return (sum(two_three), one)
```