# Python3 Sorting List of Tuples With Lambda and Sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I have a list of tuples sorted by the second element like so:

```
[('7', 10), ('2', 9), ('8', 9)]
```

I would like to sort them by their first element like so:

```
[('2',9),('7', 10),('8', 9)]
```

I have tried:

```
test_val = [('7', 10), ('2', 9), ('8', 9)]
test_val.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

which I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

However, the list is not sorted.

Real data example:

Before Attempt:

```
[('7', 10), ('2', 9), ('8', 9), ('6', 8), ('24', 8), ('3', 7), ('5', 7), ('9', 6), ('35', 6), ('15', 5), ('16', 5), ('1', 4), ('14', 4), ('17', 3), ('19', 3), ('12', 2), ('39', 2), ('26', 1), ('25', 1), ('22', 0)]
```

After Attempt:

```
[('1', 4), ('12', 2), ('14', 4), ('15', 5), ('16', 5), ('17', 3), ('19', 3), ('2', 9), ('22', 0), ('24', 8), ('25', 1), ('26', 1), ('3', 7), ('35', 6), ('39', 2), ('5', 7), ('6', 8), ('7', 10), ('8', 9), ('9', 6)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is, too sorted.  Note that your sort key is a *string*, not an integer.  Perhaps what you *want* is

```
test_val.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was having a heck of a time with it! I'll accept when I can

Comment: Glad you're problem is fixed.  Been there.