# list all items from list of tuples that share a value

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

`l = [(x,y,2),(x,y,3),(x,y,4),(x,y,2),(x,y,2),(x,y,3)]`

I need to extract tuples that share the last value into a list of lists of tuples:

`nl = [[(x,y,2),(x,y,2),(x,y,2)],[(x,y,3),(x,y,3)]]`

I don't know the last value of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## with modules

Using groupby from itertools you can group with a lambda by first sorting with that same lambda and then grouping. With a list comprehension you then group together all the groupings and filter out everything that is of length 1 to get rid of tuples that do not share values.

```
from itertools import groupby

tuples = [(1, 2, 2), (3, 1, 3), (1, 2, 4), (8, 9, 2), (12, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3)]

tuple_tail = lambda (first, mid, last): last

tuples.sort(key=tuple_tail)

print filter(lambda item: len(item) > 1, [list(group) for key, group in groupby(tuples, tuple_tail)])
```

## without modules

So this one isn't the best solution but it's a solution. I defined some helper functions that

1. `retrieves last of tuple`
2. `compares equality of two tuples`.

Then wrote a custom group function that searches for all elements that are equal by using `filter` and then `map` that across all elements to obtain a list with all possible groupings *(group all)*. I couldn't think of a way of using a list comprehension without making a mess so I went with `reduce` and wrote a function to remove elements that were duplicates and/or length of 1 *(fn)*. This could surely be optimized if you used `set` or maybe just a different approach in general. Hope this helps you find whatever that *approach* will be.

```
tuples = [(1, 2, 2), (3, 1, 3), (1, 2, 4), (8, 9, 2), (12, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3)]
# helper functions
tuple_tail = lambda (first, mid, last): last
is_tuples_equal = lambda tuple1, tuple2: tuple_tail(
    tuple1) == tuple_tail(tuple2)

# groups by last (_,_,last)
group_by_last = lambda tuple: filter(
    lambda item: is_tuples_equal(item, tuple), tuples)

# get all groupings
group_all = map(group_by_last, tuples)

# if group is not in list and not length of 1 insert into list
fn = lambda acc, val: acc if val in acc or len(val) == 1 else acc + [val]

print reduce(fn, group_all, [])
```

## with list comprehension

If you create a dictionary and use the `tuple_tail` values of each tuple as the `key` and make the `value` as the all the tuples that contain that `key` as their tail. You can then use a list comprehension to accumulate the values of the dictionary and dis include elements of length less than 1.

```
tuples = [(1, 2, 2), (3, 1, 3), (1, 2, 4), (8, 9, 2), (12, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3)]

mydict = dict()

create = lambda tupl: mydict.update({tuple_tail(tupl): [tupl]})
update = lambda tupl: mydict[tuple_tail(tupl)].append(tupl)
tuple_tail = lambda (first, mid, last): last

populate = lambda tupl: update(tupl) if tuple_tail(tupl) in mydict else create(tupl)
map(populate, tuples)

print [tuple for tuple in mydict.values() if len(tuple) > 1]
```

## end results

```
[[(1, 2, 2), (8, 9, 2), (12, 1, 2)], [(3, 1, 3), (0, 1, 3)]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without importing any additional module? Preferably as a list comprehension?

Comment: @dyb after some thinking I got it ! Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dict to group the item with same last element

```
x,y= 'x','y'

l = [(x,y,2),(x,y,3),(x,y,4),(x,y,2),(x,y,2),(x,y,3)]
res = {}
for item in l:
  if item[2] not in res:
    res[item[2]] = []
  res[item[2]].append(list(item))

print filter( lambda x: len(x) > 1 , res.values())

[['x', 'y', 2], ['x', 'y', 2], ['x', 'y', 2]], [['x', 'y', 3], ['x', 'y', 3]]
```

or using pandas

```
l = pd.Series( [(x,y,2),(x,y,3),(x,y,4),(x,y,2),(x,y,2),(x,y,3) ])

print [ line[1].tolist() for line in l.groupby( lambda x: l[x][2] ) if len(line[1]) > 1]

[[('x', 'y', 2), ('x', 'y', 2), ('x', 'y', 2)], [('x', 'y', 3), ('x', 'y', 3)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, sort according to last elements (You can use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3121985/1746852))

Then, group them. You can simply use a `for loop`. A pseudocode is:

```
cur_value = list[0][2] #second element of first tuple
llt = []; #list_of_list_of_tuples
for tuple in list:
     l_tpl = []
     if cur_value == tuple[2]:
         l_tpl.append(tuple)
     else:
         if len(l_tpl) > 1:
             llt.append(l_tpl)
if len(l_tpl) > 1:
     llt.append(l_tpl)  # we need to add the last list of tuples.
```

I haven't tested and I'm not sure of the syntax.

Comment: You should elaborate on how to group them for a complete answer

Comment: Also OP wants to remove (x,y,4).

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai, sure I've written a pseudo code, thanks for feedback.

Comment: @SangbokLee That is also included.