# How to sort a list containing objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
lst = []

class DATA:
    def __init__(self):
        s = ['','']

def fillLst():
    d1 = DATA()
    d1.s[0] = 'zebra'
    d1.s[1] = 23

    d2 = DATA()
    d2.s[0] = 'airplane'
    d2.s[1] = 435

    d1 = DATA()
    d1.s[0] = 'aira'
    d1.s[1] = 211


    lst.append(d1)
    lst.append(d2)
    lst.append(d3)
```

When I print the list I get the following:

```
zebra - 23
aira - 211
airplane - 435
```

Now I want to sort the list so that I get this output:

```
aira - 211
airplane - 435
zebra - 23
```

So how can I sort the list with the `Data` objects in it?

Comment: What have you tried to tackle this so far? There's many good questions here and also a really good official [howto on sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: The code you posted is full of typos (missing `self`, `d1` instead of `d3`...) and can't even be executed. Please paste the *exact* code that caused you a problem!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda data: data.s[0])
```

If you want to sort elements in `lst` by `s[0]`.

`sorted` function has a parameter `key` that you can specify a function that returns the key to sort.

[sorted function in Python Document](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted):

> sorted(iterable[, key][, reverse])
>
> ...
>
> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).