# Sorted method: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numpy

I have a problem using `sorted()` method. I am using this method inside a loop to sort a list which I am upgrading in every step of the loop. The first iteration works but the second an beyond doesn't and give me the next error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import math

Poblacion = 10
pressure = int(0.3*Poblacion)
mutation_chance = 0.08

Modelo = np.array([[0.60,0.40,0.90],[0.26,0.20,0.02],[0.80,0.00,0.05]])

x = np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0],[0.70,0.50,0.90],[0.10,0.40,0.20]])
y = np.array([[4.10,0.72,2.30],[1.43,0.30,1.01],[0.40,0.11,0.18]])

def crearIndividuo():
    return[np.random.random((3, 3))]

def crearPoblacion(): 
    return [crearIndividuo() for i in range(Poblacion)]

def calcularFitness(individual): 
    error = 0
    i=0
    for j in x:
        error += np.array(individual).dot(j)-y[i]
        i += 1
        error = np.linalg.norm(error,ord=1) 
        fitness = math.exp(-error)
    return fitness

def selection_and_reproduction(population):
    puntuados = [ (calcularFitness(i), i) for i in population] 
    puntuados = [i[1] for i in sorted(puntuados)] 
    population = puntuados

    selected =  puntuados[(len(puntuados)-pressure):] 

    j=0
    while (j < int(len(population)-pressure)):
        padre = rd.sample(selected, 2)

        population[j] = 0.5*(np.array(padre[0]) + np.array(padre[1]))
        j += 1
        population[j] = 1.5*np.array(padre[0]) - 0.5*np.array(padre[1])
        j += 1
        population[j] = -0.5*np.array(padre[0]) + 1.5*np.array(padre[1])
        j += 1
    return population

population = crearPoblacion()

for l in range(3):
    population = selection_and_reproduction(population)

print("final population: ", population)
```

The error occurs in the line:

```
puntuados = [i[1] for i in sorted(puntuados)]
```

I can't figure out what I m doing wrong (I am not an expert in python). Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like `puntuados` is a list of tuples. Refer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples) to see how to use `sorted` correctly.

Comment: This error is raised when a boolean array is used in a context that requires a simple True/False value.  Here it appears to be the comparison required for sorting.  A test like `x<y` produces a boolean array if `x` or `y` is a numpy array.  Try for example `np.array([1,2,3])<3`.

Comment: Notice that the sidebar shows many SO questions about the same error message.  Pay special attention to how `puntuados` changes from one iteration to the next. What was it like when it worked, and was different when it didn't.

Comment: @hpaulj I used "type(puntuados)" and its give me "<class 'list'>" in both iterations. I also checked the type and len of pupolation (it give me a list and len=10 in both iterations).

Also sometimes the code can complete the second iteration just to get stuck in the third one.

Comment: @StutiRastogi thanks a lot! that post help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 13):

The problem arises where the tuples share the same first element, so

```
sorted(puntuados)
```

has to compare the second elements of the two tuples to determine their relative order, at which point you encounter this exception.

You can use

```
sorted(graded, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

to solve your problem, if you only want to sort based on the first element of the tuples.