# How do you copy a list into another list in python?

Tags: python

I have a list something like below-
Xlist -

```
[('00:04:F2:FF:7A:1D'    -88), ('4C:49:E3:64:9D:D6'  -63),  
 ('00:EC:0A:87:61:F8'    -58), ('CC:9F:7A:99:0D:EA'  -80)]
```

I need the list to be sorted in following way-
YList-

```
[('4C:49:E3:64:9D:D6'    -63), ('00:EC:0A:87:61:F8'  -58),  
 ('CC:9F:7A:99:0D:EA'    -80), ('00:04:F2:FF:7A:1D'  -88)]
```

I am a beginner in python.
How to copy the elements in the above format?

Comment: is there a comma between the string and the integer?

Comment: sooo, what's the sorting key?

Comment: Don't you need a comma between a string and int in this tuple?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the sorting order?

Comment: Mac address is itself can be considered as a key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: I want 4C:49:E3:64:9D:D6 to be printed first, then 00:EC:0A:87:61:F8 and then I want CC:9F:7A:99:0D:EA

Comment: what is your order criteria?

Comment: @CAAnusha the Mac address cannot be considered as key for your output CC:9F:7A:99:0D:EA would come first in descending order and 00:04:F2:FF:7A:1D would come first in ascending order

Comment: Why is the title asking about copying something when the question is really about sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to sort the list in descending order. If you need to keep the original list, you could do it using [`sorted()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.sorted) builtin function

```
xlist = [('00:04:F2:FF:7A:1D', -88), ('4C:49:E3:64:9D:D6', -63),
         ('00:EC:0A:87:61:F8', -58), ('CC:9F:7A:99:0D:EA', -80)]
ylist = sorted(xlist, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(ylist)
```

You also may sort the xlist inplace using [`list.sort()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.list.sort) method:

```
xlist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(xlist)
```

Comment: output:- [('00:EC:0A:87:61:F8', -58), ('4C:49:E3:64:9D:D6', -63), ('CC:9F:7A:99:0D:EA', -80), ('00:04:F2:FF:7A:1D', -88)] which is correct but in question wrongly given output as [('4C:49:E3:64:9D:D6'    -63), ('00:EC:0A:87:61:F8'  -58),  
 ('CC:9F:7A:99:0D:EA'    -80), ('00:04:F2:FF:7A:1D'  -88)] need edit@C A Anusha