# How to sort list of lists by first value in inner list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list of lists

```
[
   ["c",2,5],
   ["bb",6,2],
   ["a",7,11],
   ...
]
```

I want it sorted like the following :

```
[
   ["a",7,11],
   ["bb",6,2],
   ["c",2,5],       
   ...
]
```

Sorting by each lists first value.  How would this be done? (So it was sorted by `a < bb < c`)

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: I don't agree with the proposed dupe target. I asks about sorting based on the second element of the sublists, and interpolating from the accepted answer might leave OP with the impression that they would have to use `lambda sub: sub[0]` as the key.

Comment: using `s = sorted([["c",2,5], ["bb",6,2], ["a",7,11],],key=lambda x:x[0])` according to the dupe works as well - it is just not needed here, as the default behaviour is sorting based in 0th index. Your answer is valid and valuable, the dupe is the "more general" answer to this question. I do not think we need 10 questions about how to sort by the 1st, 2nd, 3rd .... 10th element - nor do we need 10 canonical answers to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.sort` and `sorted` already sort lexicographically. Or in other words, all you have to do is issue `yourlist.sort()` or `result = sorted(yourlist)`.

Comment: Won't this sort by 1st value, then the 2nd, then the 3rd though?

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, so?

Comment: Well that's not the same as sorting by only the 1st value, e.g. `sorted([["a",2], ["a", 1]])` vs `sorted([["a",2], ["a", 1]], key=lambda x: x[0])` (may not be relevant for the OP's example of course)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I don't see how that is relevant here. The sublists in both outputs are clearly sorted by their first value. For the first result, they also happen to be sorted by the second value, but that was not a constraint on the question.

Comment: well they say "Sorting by each lists first value", there is no implied extra sorting, but I guess we do disagree

Comment: @Chris_Rands Now, an interesting question we could investigate is whether `key=lambda x: x[0]` is a performance optimization if you anticipate lots of lists that share their first value(s), or if the overhead of a function call makes the redundant comparisons faster in the end.

Comment: yes I don't know about performance but `operator.itemgetter(0)` would likely be faster than using `lambda` anyway

Comment: @Chris_Rands they did not say *only* by the first value, in that case I think we would need the `key`. ;)