# sorting a list with sub-lists in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I have this list with sublists:

```
[[39, 4, 43], [23, 3, 26], [46, 5, 51], [66, 15, 51], [66, 7, 73], [10, 2, 12], [79, 8, 87]]
```

I need to sort the lists in order of the third element in each sub-list. But in case two or more of them are equals like in this case:

```
[46, 5, 51], [66, 15, 51]
```

the algorithm when sorting should put first the sublist with the biggest first element, so the wanted output should be like this.

```
 [[79, 8, 87],[66, 7, 73],[66, 15, 51],[46, 5, 51],[39, 4, 43],[23, 3, 26],[10, 2, 12]]
```

Any tip to go through this? thanks or your time and help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set up your sort order as a tuple like this:

```
l = [[39, 4, 43], [23, 3, 26], [46, 5, 51], [66, 15, 51], [66, 7, 73], [10, 2, 12], [79, 8, 87]]

sorted(l, key = lambda x: (x[2],x[0]), reverse=True)
```

result:

> [[79, 8, 87],  [66, 7, 73],  [66, 15, 51],  [46, 5, 51],  [39, 4, 43],
>   [23, 3, 26],  [10, 2, 12]]

Answer (score 2):

There is also [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to do this kind of sorting:

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = [[39, 4, 43], [23, 3, 26], [46, 5, 51], [66, 15, 51], [66, 7, 73], [10, 2, 12], [79, 8, 87]]

sorted(l, key=itemgetter(2, 0), reverse=True)
```