# Where does the lambda parameter originate?

Tags: python

I refer to the solution given for [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples).

```
sorted_by_second = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

or

```
data.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])  # sorts in place
```

Where is *tup* passed to the lambda function in either sort function?

Comment: I recommend you to read [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) article.

Answer (score 1):

`tup` is the argument to `lambda`.

```
lambda tup: tup[1]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def anonymous_func(tup):
    return tup[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

By `sort` itself. The `key` parameter is a callback function which `sort` calls on each element of the sequence it is sorting. It lets you write something like the following in a more concise manner:

```
new_data = [(tup[1], tup) for tup in data]
tmp  = sorted(data)
sorted_by_second = [orig for _, orig in tmp]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the lambda function `lambda tup: tup[1]`, tup refers to the element of list `data`, and `tup[1]` refers to the second element of the item.

When you pass this to [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function, you tell it to use the second element of the item in the list as a comparison key, so the result you get is the sorted list on the second element

From the docs

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, key=str.lower). The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

Hence the behaviour is as follows

```
In [54]: data = [[4,5,6], [1,2,3], [7,8,9]]                                                                                                                                                             

In [55]: sorted_by_second = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1]) 

In [56]: sorted_by_second                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[56]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Note that you can also use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to do the same thing, which automatically picks the second element from the tuple

```
In [60]: import operator  
In [64]: data = [[4,5,6], [1,2,3], [7,8,9]]                                                                                                                                                             
In [65]: sorted_by_second = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))                                                                                                                                    
In [66]: sorted_by_second                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[66]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `key` is a transform function applied to each element of the array to provide a new value, which will then be used to sort the array. Essentially this makes it such that an element should be sorted before an element based if `key(a) < key(b)` rather than `a < b`.

The `list.sort` and `sorted` functions will call `key` for each element individually.