# Sorting a list using argsort in Numpy?

Tags: python

I have a list in python and the first numbers are `[[29.046875, 1], [33.65625, 1], [18.359375, 1], [11.296875, 1], [36.671875, 1], [23.578125, 1],.........,[34.5625, 1]]`

The above list is given an id of `listNumber`. I'm trying to use numpy.argsort to sort it based on the float elements:

```
listNumber = np.array(listNumber)
print(np.argsort(listNumber))
```

But this gives me the following but not sure why:

```
[[1 0]
 [1 0]
 [1 0]
 ...
 [1 0]
 [1 0]
 [1 0]]
```

Why is this returning this? and is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples by the element at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index)

Comment: why are you using `numpy` to sort a `list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so i think there's two things going on here:

1- Your list is a list of lists

2- The 'argsort' function:

> returns the indices that *would* sort an array.

According to the documentation.

So what is happening is the function reads through each item of the list, which in itself is a list, say index 0 is:

> [29.046875, 1]

Then it is saying, okay this is another list so let me sort it and then return a number based on *where it would go if it was the new index*:

> [29.046875, 1] -> [1, 0]

Because 1 would come before 29 if it was sorted in ascending order.
It does this for every nested list then gives you a final list containing all these 1's and 0's.

This answers the first question. Another user was able to answer the second :)

Answer (score 2):

You must set axis like:

```
import numpy as np

l = [[29.046875, 1], [33.65625, 1], [18.359375, 1], [11.296875, 1], [36.671875, 1], [23.578125, 1],[34.5625, 1]]
l = np.argsort(l, axis=0)  # sorts along first axis (down)
print(l)
```

output:

```
[[3 0]
 [2 1]
 [5 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 4]
 [6 5]
 [4 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
sortedList = listNumber[listNumber[:,0].argsort(axis=0)]
print(sortedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why people like using predone functions instead of using their own algorithm.  Anyway, you are using argsort in a bad way. argsort returns an array containing the INDEXES of your elements, thos are 2 examples :

Code 1:

```
import numpy as geek 

# input array 

in_arr = geek.array([ 2, 0,  1, 5, 4, 1, 9]) 

print ("Input unsorted array : ", in_arr)  

out_arr = geek.argsort(in_arr) 

print ("Output sorted array indices : ", out_arr) 

print("Output sorted array : ", in_arr[out_arr])
```

Output :

```
Input unsorted array :  [2 0 1 5 4 1 9]
Output sorted array indices :  [1 2 5 0 4 3 6]
Output sorted array :  [0 1 1 2 4 5 9]
```

Code 2:

```
# Python program explaining 
# argpartition() function 

import numpy as geek 

# input 2d array 

in_arr = geek.array([[ 2, 0, 1], [ 5, 4, 3]]) 

print ("Input array : ", in_arr)  


# output sorted array indices 

out_arr1 = geek.argsort(in_arr, kind ='mergesort', axis = 0) 

print ("Output sorteded array indices along axis 0: ", out_arr1) 

out_arr2 = geek.argsort(in_arr, kind ='heapsort', axis = 1) 

print ("Output sorteded array indices along axis 1: ", out_arr2)
```

Output:

```
Input array :  [[2 0 1]
 [5 4 3]]
Output sorteded array indices along axis 0:  [[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
Output sorteded array indices along axis 1:  [[1 2 0]
 [2 1 0]]
```

I am supposing that your data is stored in `listnumber`

```
import numpy as np
new_listnumber = listnumber[:, 0]
index_array = np.argsort(new_listnumber , axis=0)
New_val = listnumber[index_array] 
print(New_val)
```