# How to sort a python 2 dimensional array in python

Tags: python, sorting, columnsorting

I am trying to make a leaderboard in python and I have the following dict:
`points = [("Bob",12),("Steve",7),("Alice",9)]`
I am trying to sort it into the following dict:
`points = [("Bob",12),("Alice",9),("Steve",7)]`
How would I do this programatically.

I have tried
`sorteddata = sorted(data,key=itemgetter(1))` 
to no avail.

Thanks in advance, - Evan

Comment: `reverse=True` will help. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: Try `print(sorted(points, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))`

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index

Comment: That's not really a two-dimensional array, as the two "columns" can't vary freely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list/tuple of lists/tuples by the element at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index)

Comment: `..to no avail.` - why doesn't this work? `I have the following dict: ..` - `points` is not a dict, it is a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:-

```
pts = list(points)
pts.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Output:-

```
[('Bob', 12), ('Alice', 9), ('Steve', 7)]
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this answer is that you are trying to sort a python dict object, which returns with a AttributeError.

Comment: @EGE, You can then convert it into a list first to sort. I have updated the code. Hope this solves your error

Answer (score 0):

The `SortedDict` in the `sortedcontainers` package serves as a `dict` object with sorted **keys**. (http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html)

To sort by **values**, there is also the `ValueSortedDict` in `sortedcollections`.(http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcollections/valuesorteddict.html)

Otherwise, a pure `builtin` function like this might help:

```
def sort_dict_by_values(dictionary):
    return dict(sorted(list(dictionary), key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True))
```