# How to sort two lists and plot them?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a tool to plot wich word was how many times used in a large number of rap genius lyrics.

I already extracted to two lists: one for the name of the word. the other one for the amount the word was used.

```
list_name=["I","you","the"]
list_count=[23,42,12]
```

the values at the same index are the pairs. I'm not sure if this is the most useful way but that's how I can do a bar chart representing every word and the count of it. Now I want to sort it by the highest count number. 
If I sort list_count I can't really transfer this to make the list_name in the same order as the list_count.

Any suggestions? I tried dictionarys but I couldn't find a way how they were useful.

Comment: Put each pair into a container, then sort using the container. One common container is a tuple, e.g. `("I", 23)`. Then you just need to do `sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1])`.

Comment: How do I sort a list of tuples by one of its items?

Comment: See the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index

Answer (score 2):

### Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html)

- Create the dataframe and sort the values with [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': list_name, 'count': list_count}).sort_values('count', ascending=False)

# plot
p = plt.bar(x='name', height='count', data=df)
```

[image]

### Use [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

- `list(zip(list_name, list_count))` zips the two list into a list of tuples
- [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) sorts by ascending (smallest to largest)

  - `[::-1]` reverses the array

```py
import numpy as np

# create numpy array with dtypes
t = np.array(list(zip(list_name, list_count)), dtype = [('name', 'S10'), ('count', int)])

# sort array
t = np.sort(t, order=['count'])[::-1]

# plot
plt.bar(x=t['name'], height=t['count'])
```

Comment: Thank you ! didn't tried out pandas before

Answer (score 1):

you can create a tuple, sort by a value in the tuple and get your lists again afterwards. This is not optimal, but it suffices

eg.:

```
list_name=["I","you","the"]
list_count=[23,42,12]

aux = [(name, count) for name, count in zip(list_name, list_count)]
aux = sorted(aux, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)

list_name=[x[0] for x in aux]
list_count=[x[0] for x in aux]
```

I suggest that you take a look at zip and tuples
they are really handy

Comment: Thank You! Solved it !

Answer (score 0):

The way you have structured your data will make it difficult to perform this task. Have you considered instead creating [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) instead?

Your data above would look like this:

```
names_and_counts = [("I", 23), ("you", 42), ("the", 12)]
```

Then, you could sort the list above like so:

```
sorted_by_count = sorted(names_and_counts, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tuple using your lists.

```
list_name=["I","you","the"]
list_count=[23,42,12]
pairs = list(zip(list_name, list_count))
```

The output for `pairs` will look like this:

```
[('I', 23), ('you', 42), ('the', 12)]
```

You can now sort them based on values using:

```
sorted(pairs)
```

Your sorted list will look like.

```
[('the', 12), ('I', 23), ('you', 42)]
```