# How to sort a list of tuples, by the second tuple element?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list like this:

```
[('TIPE_ORG', 'Corea'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'United Kingdom'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'Russia'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'Germany'),('TIPE_PER', 'Pepe Martínez')]
```

I want it to be sorted by text length from largest to smallest of the second parameter
Let it be like this:

```
[('TIPE_ORG', 'United Kingdom'),('TIPE_PER', 'Pepe Martínez'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'Germany'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'Russia'),('TIPE_ORG', 'Corea')]
```

I have tried to do this, but having two parameters does not order it for the second, but for the first TIPE_ORG:

```
x.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index

Comment: But lambda is for ordering numbers, right?

Comment: @lamda can do evrey thing you till it to do. see my answer.

Comment: `key=callback_function`. lambda is an anonymous function. Here you can learn about lambda functions: https://realpython.com/python-lambda/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list/tuple of lists/tuples by the element at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` method with a lambda function as below.

```
lst=[('TIPE_ORG', 'Corea'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'United Kingdom'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'Russia'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'Germany'),('TIPE_PER', 'Pepe Martínez')]

sorted(lst,key=lambda key:len((key[1])),reverse=True)
```

Output will be

```
[('TIPE_ORG', 'United Kingdom'),
('TIPE_PER', 'Pepe Martínez'),
('TIPE_ORG', 'Germany'),
('TIPE_ORG', 'Russia'),
('TIPE_ORG', 'Corea')]
```

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by sorting inplace with `sort` method or sorting and return anew sorted list with `sorted` method. for the `equality` decition, we use `lambda` function. see below:

```
my_list=[('TIPE_ORG', 'Corea'), ('TIPE_ORG', 'United Kingdom'),('TIPE_PER', 'Pepe Martínez')]

my_new_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda this_tup:len(this_tup[1]), reverse=True)
```

or

```
sort(my_list, key=lambda this_tup:len(this_tup[1]), reverse=True)
```

you can refer to this link they have good examples about `lambda expressions` and how to use it.

[lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

Comment: Apart from the fact that this answer sorts alphabetically and not on length, it is discouraged to provide an answer if the question already has an answer elsewhere.

Comment: i am fixing my answer. patience please. i dont know what you talking about @Ronald. now you can remove the down vote.