# Sort list of dictionaries according to the list of values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

The list of dictionaries:

```
 list_dict = [{'a': 'car', 'b': 4}, {'a': 'train', 'b': 10}, {'a': 'flight', 'b': 6}, {'a': 'bike', 'b': 2}]
```

I want to sort the list of dictionaries with key **a** according to the list of values:

```
a_list = ["flight", "bike", "train", "car"]
```

The output I want:

```
[{'a': 'flight', 'b': 6}, {'a': 'bike', 'b': 2}, {'a': 'train', 'b': 10}, {'a': 'car', 'b': 4}]
```

It would be prefered not to use any loops for the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list/tuple of lists/tuples by the element at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
list_dict.sort(key=lambda x:a_list.index(x['a']))
```

Comment: @OP - Note that the above answer sorts the dict *in place*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(sorted(list_dict, key=lambda k: a_list.index(k["a"])))
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"a": "flight", "b": 6},
    {"a": "bike", "b": 2},
    {"a": "train", "b": 10},
    {"a": "car", "b": 4},
]
```