# How to calculate the midpoints of each triangle edges of an icosahedron

Tags: python, algorithm, math, geometry, uniform

Am trying to compute the midpoints of each triangle edges of an icosahedron to get an icosphere which is the composion of an icosahedron subdivided in 6 or more levels. i tried to calculate the newly created vertices of each edges but some points wore missing. I tried to normalize each mid point but still the points woren't evenly spread out and some points wore missing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_points = 12
indices = np.arange(0, num_points, dtype='float')
r = 1

vertices = [ [0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0] ] # poles

# icosahedron
for i in range(num_points):
    theta = np.arctan(1 / 2) * (180 / np.pi) # angle 26 degrees
    phi = np.deg2rad(i * 72)
  
    if i >= (num_points / 2):
        theta = -theta
        phi = np.deg2rad(36 + i * 72)

    x = r * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
    y = r * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
    z = r * np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))

    vertices.append([x, y, z])

vertices = np.array(vertices)
```

Icosahedron:

[image: icosahedron]

```
# Triangle Subdivision

for _ in range(2):
    for j in range(0, len(vertices), 3):
        v1 = vertices[j]
        v2 = vertices[j + 1]  
        v3 = vertices[j + 2]

        m1_2 = ((v1 + v2) / 2)
        m2_3 = ((v2 + v3) / 2)
        m1_3 = ((v1 + v3) / 2)

        m1_2 /= np.linalg.norm(m1_2)
        m2_3 /= np.linalg.norm(m2_3)
        m1_3 /= np.linalg.norm(m1_3)
        
        vertices = np.vstack([vertices, m1_2, m2_3, m1_3,])
   
print(vertices)
plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d').scatter(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], vertices[:, 2])
plt.show()
```

icosphere attempt:

[image: icosphere attempt]

I used this as reference to create an `icosahedron` https://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_sphere.html
and what am expecting to achive is this:

Geodesic polyhedro:

[image: Geodesic polyhedron]

I tried debugging the subdivision of each edges and it performed well:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


vertices = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1]]
vertices = np.array(vertices)
for j in range(2):
    for i in range(0, len(vertices), 3):
        v1 = vertices[i]
        v2 = vertices[i + 1]
        v3 = vertices[i + 2]

        m1_2 = (v1 + v2) / 2
        m1_3 = (v1 + v3) / 2
        m2_3 = (v2 + v3) / 2

        vertices = np.vstack([vertices, m1_2, m1_3, m2_3])

plt.figure().add_subplot().scatter(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1])
plt.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], '-ok')
plt.show()
```

Midpoints of each edgeL

[image: midpoints of each edge]

Comment: So you're trying to get the list of points that's the center of each face on a d20? Or you're trying to take the midpoint between each of the edges on a d20?

Comment: points are in coordinates x, y, z. Am trying to calculate the midpoints between each edge that compose a triangle so it can perform the humble icosphere which we subdivide each edge and each level we get more faces of triangles

Comment: I mean a 20 sided die, the die most commonly used in Dungeons and Dragons, another name for an icosahedron.

Comment: oh i see now what u mean by d20

Comment: So, you have the vertices of the d20. But right now, these are just points floating out in space, and you need to figure out how the vertices are connected. Maybe for each vertex, you can figure out which are the 5 vertices nearest to that vertex, and that will indicate your edge (not actually sure if this works, but intuitively seems true)? Then from there you have your edges, and from there calculating the midpoints becomes easy.
I think there's probably a better way to figure out which vertices are connected, but that's my take anyway.

Comment: it seems true if i follow the logic but i don't know how would i figure out which are  the 5 vertices nearest to that vertex

Comment: For each vertex, you'll want to take the distance between each other point and the index of that point as a tuple and put it in a list. You'll want to [sort by the distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index). Take the first five members of the list, and those are your closest vertices.

Comment: could you give me some example? i didn't quite understand the part where we get the index of that point as a tuple and put it in a list.

Comment: Do you need the `m1_2 /= np.linalg.norm(m1_2)` before normalisation the m12 would be the mid point.

Comment: i just tried to normalize it but if u think of better solution i would be appreciated

Comment: Remember to normalize with respect to the center of your icosahedron, and then multiply them using `r = half the distance between your poles`, in order to make all your points lie on a sphere that has those same poles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Pardon the JavaScripty answer (because that's easier for showing things off in the answer itself =), and the "cabinet projection", which is a dead simple way to turn 3D into 2D but it'll look "strangly squished" (unless you're playing an isometric platformer =)*

Icosahedrons are basically fully defined by their edge length, so once you've decided on that one value, everything else is locked in, and you can generate your 12 icosahedron points pretty easily. In your case, if we stand the icosahedron on a "pole" at `(0,0,0)`, then its height is defined by the edge length as:

```
h = edge * sqrt(1/2 * (5 + sqrt(5)))
```

(Or if we want maximum fives, `h = edge * ((5 + 5 ** 0.5) * 0.5) ** 0.5`)

And we can generate two rings of 5 vertices each, one ring at height `h1 = edge * sqrt(1/2 - 1 / (2 * sqrt(5)));`, spaced at 2π/5 angular intervals, and then the other at height `h2 = h - h1` (no need to do additional "real" math!) with the same angular intervals, but offset by π/5.

That gives us this:

```js
function sourceCode() {
  const edge = 45;
  const h = edge * sqrt(1 / 2 * (5 + sqrt(5)));
  const poles = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, h]
  ];

  function setup() {
    setSize(300, 120);
    setProjector(150, 100);
    play();
  }

  function draw() {
    clear();
    const [bottom, top] = poles;
    const [p1, p2] = generatePoints(poles);
    drawIcosahedron(bottom, p1, p2, top);
  }

  function generatePoints(poles) {
    // get an angle offset based on the mouse,
    // to generate with fancy rotation.
    let ratio = (frame / 2000) % TAU;
    if (pointer.active) ratio = (pointer.x / width);
    const ao = TAU * ratio;

    // create our bottom and top rings:
    const r = edge * sqrt(0.5 + sqrt(5) / 10);
    const h1 = edge * sqrt(1 / 2 - 1 / (2 * sqrt(5)));
    const h2 = h - h1;
    return [h1, h2].map((h, id) => {
      const ring = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const a = ao + i * TAU / 5 + id * PI / 5;
        const p = [r * cos(a), r * sin(a), h];
        ring.push(p);
      }
      return ring;
    });
  }

  function drawIcosahedron(b, p1, p2, t) {
    b = project(...b);
    p1 = p1.map(p => project(...p));
    p2 = p2.map(p => project(...p));
    t = project(...t);

    // draw our main diagonal
    setColor(`lightgrey`);
    line(...b, ...t);
        
    // then draw our bottom ring
    p1.forEach((p, i) => {
      // connect down
      line(...b, ...p);
      // and connect self
      line(...p, ...p1[(i + 1) % 5]);
    });

    // and then our top ring
    p2.forEach((p, i) => {
      // connect down
      line(...p, ...p1[i]);
      line(...p, ...p1[(i + 1) % 5]);
      // connect self
      line(...p, ...p2[(i + 1) % 5]);
      // and because this is the last ring, connect up
      line(...t, ...p);
    });
    
    setColor(`black`);
    [b, ...p1, ...p2, t].forEach(p => point(...p));
  }

  function pointerMove() {
    redraw();
  }
}

customElements.whenDefined('graphics-element').then(() => {
  graphicsElement.loadFromFunction(sourceCode);
});
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.10.0/graphics-element.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.10.0/graphics-element.css">
<graphics-element id="graphicsElement" title="An icosahedron"></graphics-element>
```

(mouse-over that graphic for more precise 3D rotational control)

To then find all the midpoints, we *could* do a lot of maths, but why bother: we can just linearly interpolate between points:

```js
const lerp = (a,b) => [
  (a[0] + b[0]) / 2, # average for x coordinates
  (a[1] + b[1]) / 2, # average for y coordinates
  (a[2] + b[2]) / 2, # average for z coordinates
];

// We end up with six "rings". Three constructed "from below"
const m1 = p1.map((p) => avg(b, p));
const m2 = p1.map((p,i) => avg(p, p1[(i+1)%5]));
const m3 = p1.map((p,i) => avg(p, p2[i]));

// And three constructed "from above"
const m4 = p2.map((p,i) => avg(p, p1[(i+1)%5]));
const m5 = p2.map((p,i) => avg(p, p2[(i+1)%5]));
const m6 = p2.map((p) => avg(t, p));
```

So adding that to the previous graphic:

```js
function sourceCode() {
  const edge = 45;
  const h = edge * sqrt(1 / 2 * (5 + sqrt(5)));
  const poles = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, h]
  ];

  function setup() {
    setSize(300, 120);
    setProjector(150, 100);
    play();
  }

  function draw() {
    clear();
    const [bottom, top] = poles;
    const [p1, p2] = generatePoints(poles);
    drawIcosahedron(bottom, p1, p2, top);
    drawMidpoints(...generateMidPoints(bottom, p1, p2, top));
  }

  function generatePoints(poles) {
    // get an angle offset based on the mouse,
    // to generate with fancy rotation.
    let ratio = (frame / 2000) % TAU;
    if (pointer.active) ratio = (pointer.x / width);
    const ao = TAU * ratio;

    // create our bottom and top rings:
    const r = edge * sqrt(0.5 + sqrt(5) / 10);
    const h1 = edge * sqrt(1 / 2 - 1 / (2 * sqrt(5)));
    const h2 = h - h1;
    return [h1, h2].map((h, id) => {
      const ring = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const a = ao + i * TAU / 5 + id * PI / 5;
        const p = [r * cos(a), r * sin(a), h];
        ring.push(p);
      }
      return ring;
    });
  }

  function generateMidPoints(b, p1, p2, t) {
    // we could use math, but why both when we can lerp?
    const avg = (a, b) => [
      (a[0] + b[0]) / 2,
      (a[1] + b[1]) / 2,
      (a[2] + b[2]) / 2,
    ];

    const m1 = p1.map((p) => avg(b, p));
    const m2 = p1.map((p, i) => avg(p, p1[(i + 1) % 5]));
    const m3 = p1.map((p, i) => avg(p, p2[i]));
    const m4 = p2.map((p, i) => avg(p, p1[(i + 1) % 5]));
    const m5 = p2.map((p, i) => avg(p, p2[(i + 1) % 5]));
    const m6 = p2.map((p) => avg(t, p));

    return [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6];
  }

  function drawIcosahedron(b, p1, p2, t) {
    b = project(...b);
    p1 = p1.map(p => project(...p));
    p2 = p2.map(p => project(...p));
    t = project(...t);

    setColor(`lightgrey`);
    line(...b, ...t);

    p1.forEach((p, i) => {
      line(...b, ...p);
      line(...p, ...p1[(i + 1) % 5]);
    });

    p2.forEach((p, i) => {
      line(...p, ...p1[i]);
      line(...p, ...p1[(i + 1) % 5]);
      line(...p, ...p2[(i + 1) % 5]);
      line(...t, ...p);
    });

    setColor(`black`);
    [b, ...p1, ...p2, t].forEach(p => circle(...p, 2));
  }

  function drawMidpoints(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6) {
    m1 = m1.map(p => project(...p));
    m2 = m2.map(p => project(...p));
    m3 = m3.map(p => project(...p));
    m4 = m4.map(p => project(...p));
    m5 = m5.map(p => project(...p));
    m6 = m6.map(p => project(...p));
    setColor(`salmon`);
    const midpoints = [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6].flat();
    midpoints.forEach((p, i) => circle(...p, 2));
  }

  function pointerMove() {
    redraw();
  }
}

customElements.whenDefined('graphics-element').then(() => {
  graphicsElement.loadFromFunction(sourceCode);
});
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.10.0/graphics-element.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.10.0/graphics-element.min.css">
<graphics-element id="graphicsElement" title="All edge midpoints highlighted"></graphics-element>
```

(And again, mouse-over that graphic to get a better 3D feel)

That still leaves "normalizing" each newly derived vertex so that it lies on the same sphere that the original icosahedral vertices, by scaling it relative to the center as the icosahedron, with a new length equal to half the distance to our poles (i.e., the same as every vertex in our original icosahedron):

```js
function scaleToSphere(r, ...pointArrays) {
  // Nothing too fancy, just scale the vector
  // relative to the icosahedral center by moving
  // it down, scaling it, and moving it back up:
  const resize = (p) => {
    const q = [p[0], p[1], p[2] - r];
    const d = (q[0]**2 + q[1]**2 + q[2]**2)**0.5;
    p[0] = q[0] * r/d;
    p[1] = q[1] * r/d;
    p[2] = q[2] * r/d + r;
  };
  pointArrays.forEach(arr => arr.forEach(p => resize(p)));
}
```

So that really only leaves the "tedious" job of linking up all our edges... let's add `scaleToSphere` to the previous code, with a new `drawIcosaspheron` function that draws all our edges:

```js
function sourceCode() {
  const edge = 45;
  const h = edge * sqrt(1 / 2 * (5 + sqrt(5)));
  const poles = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, h]
  ];

  function setup() {
    setSize(300, 120);
    setProjector(150, 100);
    play();
  }

  function draw() {
    clear();
    const [bottom, top] = poles;
    const [p1, p2] = generatePoints();
    const midpoints = generateMidPoints(bottom, p1, p2, top);
    scaleToSphere(h / 2, ...midpoints);
    drawIcosaspheron(bottom, p1, p2, ...midpoints, top);
  }

  function scaleToSphere(r, ...pointArrays) {
    const resize = (p) => {
      const q = [p[0], p[1], p[2] - r];
      const d = (q[0] ** 2 + q[1] ** 2 + q[2] ** 2) ** 0.5;
      p[0] = q[0] * r / d;
      p[1] = q[1] * r / d;
      p[2] = q[2] * r / d + r;
    };
    pointArrays.forEach(arr => arr.forEach(p => resize(p)));
  }

  function generatePoints() {
    // get an angle offset based on the mouse,
    // to generate with fancy rotation.
    let ratio = (frame / 2000) % TAU;
    if (pointer.active) ratio = (pointer.x / width);
    const ao = TAU * ratio;

    // create our bottom and top rings:
    const r = edge * sqrt(0.5 + sqrt(5) / 10);
    const h1 = edge * sqrt(1 / 2 - 1 / (2 * sqrt(5)));
    const h2 = h - h1;
    return [h1, h2].map((h, id) => {
      const ring = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const a = ao + i * TAU / 5 + id * PI / 5;
        const p = [r * cos(a), r * sin(a), h];
        ring.push(p);
      }
      return ring;
    });
  }

  function generateMidPoints(b, p1, p2, t) {
    // we could use math, but why both when we can lerp?
    const avg = (a, b) => [
      (a[0] + b[0]) / 2,
      (a[1] + b[1]) / 2,
      (a[2] + b[2]) / 2,
    ];

    const m1 = p1.map((p) => avg(b, p));
    const m2 = p1.map((p, i) => avg(p, p1[(i + 1) % 5]));
    const m3 = p1.map((p, i) => avg(p, p2[i]));
    const m4 = p2.map((p, i) => avg(p, p1[(i + 1) % 5]));
    const m5 = p2.map((p, i) => avg(p, p2[(i + 1) % 5]));
    const m6 = p2.map((p) => avg(t, p));

    return [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6];
  }

  function drawIcosaspheron(b, p1, p2, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, t) {
    b = project(...b);
    p1 = p1.map(p => project(...p));
    p2 = p2.map(p => project(...p));
    m1 = m1.map(p => project(...p));
    m2 = m2.map(p => project(...p));
    m3 = m3.map(p => project(...p));
    m4 = m4.map(p => project(...p));
    m5 = m5.map(p => project(...p));
    m6 = m6.map(p => project(...p));
    t = project(...t);

    // Draw our mesh based on rings:
    setColor(`lightgrey`);

    // first ring:
    m1.forEach((p, i) => {
      line(...b, ...p);
      line(...p, ...m1[(i + 1) % 5]);
    });

    // second ring, which is {p1,m2}
    p1.forEach((p,i) => {
      line(...p, ...m1[i]);
      line(...p, ...m2[i]);
    });
    m2.forEach((p,i) => {
      line(...p, ...m1[i]);
      line(...p, ...m1[(i+1) % 5]);
      line(...p, ...p1[(i+1) % 5]);
    });

    // third ring, which is {m3,m4}
    m3.forEach((p,i) => {
      line(...p, ...p1[i]);
      line(...p, ...m2[i]);
      line(...p, ...m4[i]);
    });
    m4.forEach((p,i) => {
      line(...p, ...m2[i]);
      line(...p, ...m2[(i+1) % 5]);
      line(...p, ...m3[(i+1) % 5]);
    });
    
    // fourth ring, which is {p2,m5}
    p2.forEach((p,i) => {
      line(...p, ...m3[i]);
      line(...p, ...m4[i]);
      line(...p, ...m5[i]);
    });
    m5.forEach((p,i) => {
      line(...p, ...m3[(i+1) % 5]);
      line(...p, ...m4[i]);
      line(...p, ...p2[(i+1) % 5]);
    });
    
    // fifth ring, which is m6
    m6.forEach((p, i) => {
      line(...p, ...p2[i]);
      line(...p, ...m5[i]);
      line(...p, ...m5[(i + 5 - 1) % 5]);
      line(...p, ...m6[(i + 1) % 5]);
      line(...t, ...p);
    });
    
    setColor(`black`);
    [b, ...p1, ...p2, t].forEach(p => circle(...p, 2));

    setColor(`salmon`);
    [...m1, ...m2, ...m3, ...m4, ...m5, ...m6].forEach(p => circle(...p, 2));
  }

  function pointerMove() {
    redraw();
  }
}

customElements.whenDefined('graphics-element').then(() => {
  graphicsElement.loadFromFunction(sourceCode);
});
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.10.0/graphics-element.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.10.0/graphics-element.min.css">
<graphics-element id="graphicsElement" title="After spherical scaling"></graphics-element>
```

Of course, if you want to keep going, the manual edge-building is silly, but since we're building rings of vertices, we (and by "we" of course I mean "you" ;) can write our point generation to be a little smarter and automatically "merge" all new points on a ring into that same ring, so that edge building is a matter of starting with "five edges from the bottom pole to first ring", then iterating over each higher ring so that it cross-connects all points to the previous ring (as well as adding all edges of the ring itself, of course) until we reach the top pole, which just needs five edges to the ring below it.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know you could make interactive answers stuff on Stack.

Comment: You can make runnable snippets, so as long as you can import a JS library that lets you draw stuff, you can draw stuff =)

Comment: wow this is exactly what i need but could u elaborate more on the linear interpolation between points and when u normalized it, i didn't quite understand but the rest was well executed, hands down!

Comment: finding a midpoint between two vertices is effectively finding the average of the two points in x, y, and z, which we do by taking the two values (per dimension), adding them, then dividing by 2. This is identical to performing a 50:50 linear interpolation hence the use of the term. And then you run the normalization (technically normalization and scaling) on all your newly created mid points (because the original icosahedron points are already "scaled correctly").

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python answer, complete with a rotating GIF. This is a slight reimplementation of calculating the vertices based on the C++ code you said you used to base your implementation off of. I think that [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78091070/2121074) offers a much better understanding.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import io

PI = np.pi
H_ANGLE = PI / 180 * 72  # 72 degree = 360 / 5
V_ANGLE = np.arctan(1.0 / 2)  # elevation = 26.565 degree
radius = 1  # Assuming a radius of 1 for simplicity

# Array of 12 vertices (x,y,z)
vertices = np.zeros((12, 3))

# The first top vertex at (0, 0, radius)
vertices[0] = [0, 0, radius]

# Compute 10 vertices at 1st and 2nd rows
hAngle1 = -PI / 2 - H_ANGLE / 2  # start from -126 deg at 1st row
hAngle2 = -PI / 2  # start from -90 deg at 2nd row
for i in range(1, 6):
    i1 = i  # index for 1st row
    i2 = i + 5  # index for 2nd row

    z = radius * np.sin(V_ANGLE)  # elevation
    xy = radius * np.cos(V_ANGLE)  # length on XY plane

    vertices[i1] = [xy * np.cos(hAngle1), xy * np.sin(hAngle1), z]
    vertices[i2] = [xy * np.cos(hAngle2), xy * np.sin(hAngle2), -z]

    hAngle1 += H_ANGLE
    hAngle2 += H_ANGLE

# The last bottom vertex at (0, 0, -radius)
vertices[11] = [0, 0, -radius]

# Define the edges
edges = [
    (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5),
    (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 1),
    (1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10),
    (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (10, 6),
    (6, 11), (7, 11), (8, 11), (9, 11), (10, 11),
    (3, 7), (2, 6), (1, 10), (5, 9), (4, 8)
]

# Setup figure and axis for 3D plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Calculate midpoints
midpoints = [(vertices[edge[0]] + vertices[edge[1]]) / 2 for edge in edges]

# Function to update the plot for each frame
def update_with_midpoints(frame):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
    ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
    ax.set_zlim(-1.5, 1.5)
    
    # Plot vertices
    for i in range(12):
        ax.plot([vertices[i][0]], [vertices[i][1]], [vertices[i][2]], 'bo')
    
    # Draw edges
    for edge in edges:
        points = np.array([vertices[edge[0]], vertices[edge[1]]])
        ax.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2], 'r-')
    
    # Plot midpoints in green
    for midpoint in midpoints:
        ax.plot([midpoint[0]], [midpoint[1]], [midpoint[2]], 'go')
    
    ax.view_init(30, frame)

# Create an animation with midpoints included
ani_with_midpoints = FuncAnimation(fig, update_with_midpoints, frames=np.arange(0, 360, 2), blit=False)

# Save the animation as a GIF with midpoints included
gif_path_with_midpoints = "icosahedron_rotation_with_midpoints.gif"
ani_with_midpoints.save(gif_path_with_midpoints, writer='imagemagick', fps=10)
```

Comment: It's a great implementation but the edges are defined static, what i want is for each level of subdivision, multiply the number of points which are distributed evenly that compose an icosphere